# Unusually formated NetCDF to raster in R

Tags: raster, r, netcdf

Having issues relating information stored in an NetCDF in a way I haven't seen before.

nc file located here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x1eexenioclwe0l/ISCCP_HXG_total_PAR_1984_01_01_03.nc?dl=0

Can someone provide the script to convert the coordinates to lat/lon? I would typically pull the data by:

```
    library(raster)

    file <-"X.nc"
    r <- brick(file, varnames = "total_par")
```

such that I could then

```
    file2 <-"XX.nc"
    r2 <- brick(file2,varnames = total_par")
    r3<-stack(r,r2)
```

The data is needed in a raster format that would allow for this.

Comment: added the r tag

Comment: NetCDF is a file format that can store all sorts of data, structured and unstructured, and only ones structured according to a well-known form can be read directly as spatial data. This one does not have any of that spatial metadata - its a 3600x1800 matrix of values indexed by 1:3600 and 1:1800. If you know it is a global raster and in cells of 0.1 degree then you can set the coordinates and the CRS to get something georeferenced (you also need to know where the meridian is). Do you know that info?

Comment: @Spacedman, The supplemental info lists the projection as UTM. I don't see mention of a meridian. If you have time and can look, the supplemental info is here on the right hand side in a text and doc file: [link](https://data.tpdc.ac.cn/en/data/16795f34-cd08-48b0-a1d6-4f85d195ad9e/)

Comment: # in the supplemental info #

lat:  (89.95:-0.1:-89.95) N
lon:  (0.05:0.1:359.95)  E
left_up_pixel: (89.95,0.05)
down_right_pixel:  (-89.95,359.95)

Comment: gosh this is flat out crashing R for me, good find - there's no information in the lonlat arrays (just implicit 1:n), so I'd go with Spacedman's interpretation - there's no information in the file at all apart from the par numbers in that one array. Go back to the data provider and get them to write a good netcdf

Comment: Robert fixed the crash 

Comment: @mdsumner I'd assume the crash may have been due to memory limitations on your machine?

Comment: no, was a bug in terra - this is a tiny data set and terra isn't pulling it into memory with rast() - sorry I didn't mention that I was trying out with terra (raster uses ncdf4 by default to read netcdf, but terra uses GDAL as it does for every other format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read using the `raster` package:

```
z = raster("./ISCCP_HXG_total_PAR_1984_01_01_03.nc")
```

which gets me some warnings...

```
Loading required namespace: ncdf4
[1] "vobjtovarid4: **** WARNING **** I was asked to get a varid for dimension named lon BUT this dimension HAS NO DIMVAR! Code will probably fail at this point"
[1] "vobjtovarid4: **** WARNING **** I was asked to get a varid for dimension named lat BUT this dimension HAS NO DIMVAR! Code will probably fail at this point"
```

Note that trying to read using the `terra` package makes R crash for me, so I'm falling back to `raster`. I'd usually recommend `terra`.

Then set the extent to the full globe:

```
extent(z)=c(-180, 180, -90, 90)
```

Note this isn't UTM, its a 0.1 degree cell grid in lat-long:

```
> z
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1800, 3600, 6480000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

I can't see anything in the image to check this is correctly shown over, for example, land surface features:

[image]

If you want to get it into a `terra` raster object then maybe try reading it into a matrix using `ncdf4` and then manipulating it:

```
library(ncdf4)
library(terra)
nc = nc_open("./ISCCP_HXG_total_PAR_1984_01_01_03.nc")
total_par = ncvar_get(nc, "total_par")
z = flip(rast(t(total_par)))
ext(z)=c(-180, 180, -90, 90)
crs(z) = "epsg:4326"
plot(z)
```

[image]

Note that I transpose the matrix and `flip` it - I'm only doing this to get the same plot as with `raster` - I don't know is the unflipped version is correct!

Comment: That is what it should look like - its an hourly spectral measurement and only after integrating over sufficient time periods do the continents show... Thank you for this solution. I've read quite a few of your worked solutions at this point. I appreciate the time you dedicate to doing this. It has been very helpful - cheers!